# Getting AttributeError: 'SARIMAXResults' object has no attribute 'forecast_'

Tags: python, machine-learning, statsmodels

I created a SARIMAX wrapper to use and run my data with, but I got an error. I think I wrote the wrapper correctly, but I get an error. Can I get some help on this?

```
class SARIMAX_wrapper(object):

def __init__(self, data: pd.DataFrame, p_val: int, d_val: int, q_val: int, P_val: int, D_val: int, Q_val: int, s_val: int) -> None:

    self.p_val = p_val
    self.q_val = q_val
    self.d_val = d_val
    self.P_val = P_val
    self.Q_val = Q_val
    self.D_val = D_val
    self.s_val = s_val
    self.data = data
    #self.model_ = self.fit_model_()
    

def fit_model_(self) -> None:

    try:
        temp_model = SARIMAX(self.data, order=(self.p_val, self.d_val, self.q_val), seasonal_order=(self.P_val, self.D_val, self.Q_val, self.s_val))
        temp_fitted_model__ = temp_model.fit()

        #return temp_fitted_model__
        self.model_ = temp_fitted_model__
    except:
        print('Something is not right!')
        pass
    #return temp_fitted_model_
      
def forecast_(self) -> list:


    forecast_vals = self.model_.forecast(steps=12)
    

    return forecast_vals

if __name__ == '__main__':
   temp1 = SARIMAX_wrapper(data, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0)
   temp2 = temp1.fit_model_()
   results = temp2.forecast_()
```

It fails on the results line. Is there a better way to write this wrapper? Thanks!